# JQuery autocomplete doesn't work with materialize.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, materialize

I'm using Materialize, Jquery for different things. If I don't have the materialize.js file linked to my html-page the autocomplete works flawlessly but if I add the file the autocomplete stops working. Debug shows it skips the whole function. Putting the function into no conflict mode doesn't help, either:

```
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j('#'+rowid).autocomplete({});
```

Does anyone know where the issue lies?
EDIT: the whole code function:"

```
    public AutocompleteArticles(item: OrderLine) {
    const outdatedarticle: OrderLine = item;
    let rowid = $("#txtsearch" + item.ModelId).attr('id');
    let articles: any = OrderPage.Instance().AvailableArticles;
    $('#'+rowid).autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            var searchtext = request.term.toLowerCase();
            response($.map(articles, function (item) {
                if (item.ArticleNumber.toLowerCase().includes(searchtext) || item.Name.toLowerCase().includes(searchtext) || item.Description.toLowerCase().includes(searchtext) ) {
                    return {
                        label: item.ArticleNumber + ' ' + item.Description,
                        value: {
                            ModelId: null,
                            ArticleModelId: item.ModelId,
                            OfferModelId: OrderPage.Instance().ModelId,
                            Name: item.Name,
                            Discount: item.Discount,
                            Amount: item.Amount,
                            Price: item.PriceExclVat,
                            ArticleNumber: item.ArticleNumber,
                            ArticleDescription: item.Description,
                            OrderLineDescription: item.OrderLineDescription,
                            VAT: item.TaxRate
                        }
                    }
                }
            }));

        },
        select: function (event, item) {
            let articlevalues: OrderLine = item.item.value;
            let newarticle: any = outdatedarticle;
            newarticle.ArticleModelId = articlevalues.ArticleModelId;
            newarticle.ArticleNumber = articlevalues.ArticleNumber;
            newarticle.ModelId = articlevalues.ModelId;
            newarticle.OfferModelId = articlevalues.OfferModelId;
            newarticle.Price = articlevalues.Price;
            newarticle.VAT = articlevalues.VAT;
            newarticle.Amount = outdatedarticle.Amount();
            newarticle.Discount = outdatedarticle.Discount();
            newarticle.ArticleDescription = articlevalues.ArticleDescription;

            let result: OrderLine = OrderPage.Instance().AddOrderLine(newarticle);
            OrderPage.Instance().Order.OrderLines.replace(outdatedarticle, result);
        }
    });


}
```

The articles get loaded into 'AvailableArticles' on document ready. 
Html:

```
    <input id="autocomplete" class="input-field autocomplete" data-bind="value: '', attr: { id: 'txtsearch' + ModelId }, event :{ keyup: OrderPage.Instance().AutocompleteArticles }" placeholder="Zoek" />
```

I'm also using KnockoutJS. The AutocompleteArticles gets triggered by keyup events.

Comment: Can you give more of your code? You need to give the data that autocomplete has to use. Where do you define it?

Comment: Added more code, sorry! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

hmm... I suspect you need to call 

`var $j = jQuery.noConflict()`

**Before** you import `materialize`

ie, something like

```
/* index.html */
<script src = "jquery.3.1.0.js"></script>
<script>
  var $j = jQuery.noConflict()
</script>
<script src = "materialize.1.0.0.js"></script>

/* other codes */

/* nb: $, NOT $j */
$('#'+id).autocomplete({
  /* autocomplete init obj */
})
```

Comment: Sadly that doesn' seem to work. Hovering over the $('#'+id).autocomplete({}) function shows that it's using JQuery, not Materialize. So I'm stumped.

Comment: hmm.. as am I. Have you imported jquery twice? one before the `$j = jQuery.noConflict()` and once after?

Comment: I have all my files in a bundle in C#. On the page itself jQuery does not get loaded, neither does anything else that is in the bundle. 

I've gone through the process of the version where autocomplete works and the one where it doesn't. The version that doesn't  work gets additional data when the autocomplete function is called upon. A lot more undefined with the version where it does work.

Comment: They do both go through the exact same files... But the debugger never goes further towards the 'source' or 'select' of autocomplete.